# Select ancestors and immediate children of a node in a nested set tree using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, nested-sets, sql

Hoping some of you mysql experts can help me out.

I have searchtag data that is stored in a nested set.

```
TABLE searchTags

searchTagID
searchTag
lft
rgt
```

(I am using nested sets because there are times when I need to easily select entire branches of the tree.)

I would like to construct a query that will return a resultset of nodes matched with LIKE, the ancestors of each of these nodes, and the immediate children of each of these nodes.

For example, if this is my nested set...

```
                          1_tagA_22
     2_tagB1_11          12_tagB2_13           14_tagB3_21
3_taC1_4   5_taC2_10                                   15_tagC3_20
               6_tagD1_9                        16_tagD2_17    18_tagD3_19
                  7_tagE1_8
```

...and for my search needle I have LIKE CONCAT('%','tagc','%'), I would like to return something that looks like this:

```
searchTag   |   ancestors   |  immediateChildren
tagC1          tagB1,tagA       NULL
tagC2         tagB1,tagA       tagD1
tagC3          tagB3,tagA       tagD2,tagD3
```

I am currently doing this with multiple queries.  First I select a resultset of searchtags and their ancestors.  Then I loop through this resultset and for each result, I do another select to get the immediate children.  (I am including these queries below, for reference.)

This method works, but I have a feeling it is an inefficient solution and is likely to blow up sooner or later.  :)  I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this - ie is there a way to combine all of this into a single SELECT statement that is more efficient?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Reference:
I use the following to select the searchtag and the path of ancestors...

```
    SELECT 

        node.searchTag, 

        GROUP_CONCAT(parent.searchTag 
        ORDER BY parent.lft DESC
        SEPARATOR '; ') AS ancestors 


    FROM 

        searchTags AS node,
        searchTags AS parent

    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND parent.lft < node.lft
    AND node.searchTag LIKE CONCAT('%','tagc','%')
    GROUP BY node.searchTagID;
```

...and then I loop through this resultset and for each result run another query to get the immediate children (using mrbinky3000's excellent method):

```
SELECT lft, rgt INTO @parent_left, @parent_right FROM searchTags WHERE searchTagID = $id;

SELECT 

    GROUP_CONCAT(child.searchTag SEPARATOR "; ") as searchTag

FROM searchTags AS child
LEFT JOIN searchTags AS ancestor ON
    ancestor.lft BETWEEN @parent_left+1 AND @parent_right-1 AND
    child.lft BETWEEN ancestor.lft+1 AND ancestor.rgt-1
WHERE
    child.lft BETWEEN @parent_left+1 AND @parent_right-1 AND
    ancestor.searchTagID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7bac/2) is an SQL Fiddle with a solution.

The SQL is:

```
SELECT t0.title node
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(t5.title) children
      ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t6.title)
                    FROM Tree t6
                    WHERE t6.lft<t0.lft AND t6.rgt>t0.rgt
                    ORDER BY t6.lft) ancestors
FROM Tree t0
     LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT t1.lft node
                  ,MAX(t2.lft) nodeparent
            FROM Tree t1
                 INNER JOIN
                 Tree t2 ON t1.lft>t2.lft AND t1.rgt<t2.rgt
            GROUP BY t1.lft) t3 
            LEFT JOIN
            Tree t4 ON t3.node=t4.lft) t5 ON t0.lft=t5.nodeparent
GROUP BY t0.title;
```

The ancestors are a pretty straightforward subquery in the select statement.

For the children, subquery t3 creates an adjacency list by finding the ancestor of each nod that has MAX(lft) which is then joined to t4 to get the childrens name.

Feel free to put any `WHERE` clause you like at the bottom.

Answer (score -2):

Have a read of these good articles on nested sets in MySQL
http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/>http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/